# Reading config files present inside the jar in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Greetings!

I have a spring application which depends on a legacy spring app, shipped as a jar. Pls note that the legacy jar has its spring config file inside the jar itself. Well there are two properties files: app.properties and override.properties.

Now from the outer project, I can read one config property by using something like:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" ref="propertyResource"></property>
 </bean>

<bean name="propertyResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
  <constructor-arg><value>spring-config.properties</value></constructor-arg>
 </bean>
```

But I could not make it work for 2 property files. Has someone come across similar issue and found a way out? pls suggest. I tried using list for `propertyResource` bean, have two `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` beans, but of no use.

btw, just for records, I have searched (but not thoroughly) the spring documentation, so that would be next thing i will be doing, but if someone already knows the solution to this, why re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to load more than one properties file into your PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. You can do so by setting the 'locations' property instead of the 'location' property.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:app.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:override.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I have tried this one. Somehow I was not able to load property files present within jar using this method. I tried using "classpath*" too.

Comment: Can you confirm the path location of the properties files within the jar? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: Thanks Kevin for you response. These files are present at the root of jar file. I will try to rebuild the jar and update here.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Can you describe what you mean when you say you could not make it work. What is the behaviour you are seeing?

Comment: Kevin, found out that there was problem with the jar. After rebuilding the jar, and with your solution, I am able to load the config files from within the jar.  Thanks!

Comment: I am facing exact same problem in my project right now and have spent hours over it. I couldn't get this resolved this way either and I don't think there is a problem with the jar file. Can someone please help? What was the problem with your jar by the way? In my case the property file that I am trying to reference from the dependent jar file is in src/main/resources directory.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is the ignore unresolvable placeholders property:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" ref="propertyResource"></property>
  <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
```

A couple of notes:

Take a look at the [p namespace](http://blog.springsource.com/2006/11/25/xml-syntax-sugar-in-spring-20/) (note: this link is old but still relevant) for shorthand configs. Your config would become:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" 
        p:ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders="true" 
        p:locations="classpath:spring-config.properties" />
```

Also take a look at the [context namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html) (section c.2.8). Your config would become:

```
<context:property-placeholder locations="classpath:spring-config.properties" ignore-unresolvable=true"/>
```